# Complex JSON parsing in android - Multi objects and arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I am currently developing for android and using some face recognition services. The service returns some complex JSON as seen below;

EDIT - Proper JSON

```
{"photos":[{"url":"http:\/\/face.com\/images\/ph\/0b3ecef9a00b647570027e590b72c893.jpg","pid":"F@ddc704534bc71ad7271a1d07b95362ca_88f17d8482a3d3aac1d07b3062a3e29b","width":960,"height":637,"tags":[{"tid":"TEMP_F@ddc704534bc71ad7271a1d07b95362ca_88f17d8482a3d3aac1d07b3062a3e29b_54.06_45.53_1_1","recognizable":true,"threshold":59,"uids":[{"uid":"1@greene99","confidence":17}],"gid":null,"label":"","confirmed":false,"manual":false,"tagger_id":null,"width":19.58,"height":29.51,"center":{"x":54.06,"y":45.53},"eye_left":{"x":49.55,"y":38.8},"eye_right":{"x":58.4,"y":38.92},"mouth_left":{"x":49.82,"y":52.1},"mouth_center":{"x":54.77,"y":53.04},"mouth_right":{"x":58.36,"y":52.16},"nose":{"x":54.98,"y":46.3},"ear_left":null,"ear_right":null,"chin":null,"yaw":-7.59,"roll":2.27,"pitch":0.01,"attributes":{"age_est":{"value":18,"confidence":30},"age_max":{"value":24,"confidence":30},"age_min":{"value":12,"confidence":30},"face":{"value":"true","confidence":99},"gender":{"value":"female","confidence":41},"glasses":{"value":"false","confidence":73},"lips":{"value":"parted","confidence":63},"mood":{"value":"happy","confidence":61},"smiling":{"value":"true","confidence":48}}}]}],"status":"success","usage":{"used":1,"remaining":4999,"limit":5000,"reset_time_text":"Wed, 28 Mar 2012 14:20:08 +0000","reset_time":1332944408}}
```

The only thing I need to get out of it is the uid value inside the uids array. Have tried a few methods with no success, any advice?

EDIT - answer :)

```
String uid = new JSONObject(inputString).getJSONArray("photos").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("tags").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("uids").getJSONObject(0).getString("uid");
```

Comment: Those '-' chars aren't there right or are they?

Comment: You are right sorry, seems to make it easier to read they added them into there formatted return preview, they are not actually passed through.

Comment: post what you have tried, and what jsonparser you're using

Comment: Post the normal json, we can watch the json using jsonformat.com or some other json formatter. Easier than this to read...

Comment: Edited topic to the normal json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this example using the json.org library ( http://www.json.org/java/index.html ):

```
String uid = new JSONObject(inputString).getJSONArray("photos").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("tags").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("uids").getJSONObject(0).getString("uid");
```

Where input string is the string representation of your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this but it throws JSONException and dosnt work.

Comment: Now that you have posted proper JSON, I updated my code. Try it again!

Comment: Then read it and post it or try to correct the error on your own. To read the first item in a JSON Array `"array" : [{item}]` use `getJSONArray("array").getJSONObject(0)` and to get a value from a JSONObject use getX() whre X can be String, Int, ...

Comment: Your code does work, when I C&P'ed it it didnt work however when I built it up from scratch it works. Odd but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout JSONTokener

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

Comment: Thanks Shubhayu, I have parsed Json before just none that has been this complex as it seems to be an array inside an array inside an array. Any more relevant to the problem help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is not a proper JSON.
use jsonlint http://jsonlint.com/